# Norm distance in a Banach space

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, banach-spaces, norms

Consider the Hilbert space $l_2(\mathbb{N})$ under the square summable norm $\Vert \cdot \Vert_2.$ Let us define a new norm $||| \cdot ||| $ equivalent to $\Vert \cdot \Vert_2$ such that the closed unit ball concerning the new norm is defined by $  U= ccl(S_{l_2} \cup Y)$, where $Y=${ $\pm x_n^{\pm}: n \geq 2$ }, $x_n^+=(\frac{n}{n+1},0, ..., 1,0,...)$, $1$ in the n-th place and $x_n^-=(\frac{n}{n+1},0, ..., -1,0,...)$, $-1$ in the n-th place. Here, $U$ is the unit ball of new norm $||| \cdot |||$ on $l_2$. Both norms are equivalent in the sense that $S_{l_2} \subseteq U \subseteq \sqrt{2} S_{l_2}$.

I take $y_n=e_1 + e_n$ and $z_n=e_1-e_n$. Then $\Vert y_n \Vert_2 = \sqrt{2}$ = $\Vert z_n \Vert_2$. However, I am stuck on finding out the norm distance of $y_n$ and $z_n$ w.r.t. the new norm.i.e., i need to find $|||y_n |||$ and $|||z_n |||$. Could anyone guide me? I appreciate any help you can provide.

Comment: (i) What is your $x_n$? Is it $z_n$? Also, what do you then mean by "the norm distance of $x_n$ and $y_n$ w.r.t. the new norm"? Is it $|||z_n-y_n|||=2|||e_n|||$? (ii) What do you mean, specifically, by "how this new norm will behave with the elements of $l_2$ space"? (iii) Asking multiple questions in one post should be avoided.

Comment: I am sorry for the confusion. I have done the edits. Kindly help me.

Comment: Again, what do you mean by "the norm distance of $y_n$ and $z_n$ w.r.t. the new norm"?

Comment: I want to find $|||y_n|||$ and $|||z_n |||$.

Comment: Will $|||y_n |||$  ( and $|||z_n |||$) will goes to 1 as $n \to \infty$ ?